# replaceWith() doesn't work inside .hover()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery script that replaces a `.class ul li` on mouse over and reverts back to the default on mouse out. My problem is that when the mouse is out of the `li` the second function attribute doesn't work, doesn't return the original `li` and the replaced `li` takes its place.

Script:

```
$('.header-nav li:nth-child(2)').hover(
    function() {
      $( this ).replaceWith('<li><div class="new-messages-f"></div><a href="">Account</a></li>'); // Replaced
    },function() {
      $( this ).replaceWith('<li><div class="new-messages-f">89</div><a href="">Ac</a></li>'); // Original
    });
```

HTML

```
<ul class="header-nav">
  <li><a href="">Logo Here</a></li>
  <li><div class="new-messages-f">89</div><a href="">Ac</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be nth-child(1) since (0) is 1 in arrays??

Comment: @AndrewLyndem not cause as I said, the mouse over work and not the mouse out, so I get some result.

Comment: `$(this)` refers to the old `<li>` element that you deleted with `replaceWith`.

Comment: @Barmar so how do I select the new one? And don't forget that this action can happen +oo times!

Comment: @AndrewLyndem see jquery's [docs for `nth-child`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) - 'Because jQuery's implementation of :nth- selectors is strictly derived from the CSS specification, the value of n is "1-indexed",'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reason, i think this way is less  buggy, take a look:

```js
$('.header-nav li:nth-child(2)').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).find('.new-messages-f').html('77');
    $(this).find('a').html('Account');
    $(this).find('a').attr("href", "http://www.google.com/");
});
$('.header-nav li:nth-child(2)').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).find('.new-messages-f').html('89');
    $(this).find('a').html('Ac');
    $(this).find('a').attr("href", "http://www.yahoo.com/");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="header-nav">
  <li><a href="">Logo Here</a></li>
  <li style="background-color: lightgray;"><div class="new-messages-f">89</div><a href="">Ac</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you this is the classic solution that I haven't though. Howerver is there any other solution?

Comment: not that i know of at the moment (other than the other suggested solutions listed)

Answer (score 2):

When you're replacing element, you are removing the event-binding from it. May I suggest using `.html()` on `li` element instead of `replaceWith`:

```
$('.header-nav li:nth-child(2)').hover(
    function() {
      $( this ).html('<div class="new-messages-f">77</div><a href="">Account</a>'); // Replaced
    },function() {
      $( this ).html('<div class="new-messages-f">89</div><a href="">Ac</a>'); // Original
    });
```

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x8L1y8xs/

Comment: it's not working as I thought. It;s a buggy future I can admit. When you mouse over it's change, but in mouse out don't change back either. But it's time that it does.

Comment: It does work, this is simply an annoying thing with `hover`, when mouse moves away too fast, the event may not fire.  Try other solutions in this post, they may work better (faster) than replacing entire html blob.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding and removing elements, put both versions in the HTML and use `.hide()` and `.show()`.

```js
$('.header-nav li:nth-child(2)').hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".in").show();
    $(this).find(".out").hide();
}, function () {
    $(this).find(".in").hide();
    $(this).find(".out").show();
});
```

```css
.header-nav .in {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="header-nav">
    <li><a href="">Logo Here</a></li>
    <li>
        <div class="out">
            <div class="new-messages-f">89</div><a href="">Ac</a>
        </div>
        <div class="in">
            <div class="new-messages-f">89</div><a href="">Account</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```